# How can i get the box shadow to work on my navbar?

Tags: html, css

code is messy so heres the codepen https://codepen.io/Estia/pen/zYwEepB

want the navbar(class:navbar ) to have a box shadow but it doesnt seem to be working(line 38 CSS)
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD8rv.png) / `box-shadow: 0px 12px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.76);`

Comment: Take a look on z-index
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

The shadow is there, but it's hidden behind "main". Quick fix? Add this to your navbar css class

```
z-index:1;
```

Comment: tysm it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try put `z-index: 1`

By HTML hierarchy your tag `<main>` is on top of the class `navbar`.